# How to serve somefile.pdf instead of index.html as default with .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I want visitors on www.domain.com to be served with a pdf file on www.domain.com/file.pdf automatically.

The file shoudl be shown in the browser. Not downloaded. Is this possible to do with .htaccess rules?

My webhoster runs apache.

Answer (score 4):

Put this code in root directory `.Htaccess` :

```
DirectoryIndex  file.pdf
```

Comment: That yields a 403 forbidden... my pdf file is set to 777 for testing purposes